# How to avoid duplicate addition?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoid

## Problem I'm trying to solve

I have a worker process which changes an attribute of a resource(lets say MyResource) by accumulating values from some JSON messages the worker receives. I'm trying to come up with a best way to avoid duplicate accumulation even if the same JSON message is received twice or more times by the worker process.

## Here's what I've tried

### Solution 1

Every JSON message has a unique timestamp which depends on when the JSON message was created, I saved that timestamp on MyResource and rejected a JSON message if it has timestamp value lower than the one on MyResource.

#### Problem

Since the whole architecture is asynchronous, the messages might be received in any order and not necessarily in same order as they were created.

### Solution 2

I created a new attribute (say added_ids) on MyResource. Every JSON message has an unique id, I appended that id to MyResource.added_ids. And every time accumulating used added_ids for already processed JSON messages.

#### Problem

I'm using mongo to store MyResource. Every MyResource document started to blow up with this array of ids, since the JSON messages for each MyResource are a lot. Also lookup in array is an expensive operation.

## I'm looking for

I'm looking for an answer which can handle the asynchronous nature and also does not blow up my mongo documents. Also I'm not looking for an exact solution, is there a algorithm/pattern which is used to solve similar kind of problems? I tried googling, but I don't know what to call this problem to get relevant results.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right track with your second solution, however the performance might be better if you store each added_id as it's own key-val instead of in an array.

The logic is pretty straightforward: Each time you get an input from the queue, lookup in your cache whether there's an entry for that message id. If there is an entry, then don't accumulate that input. Otherwise, accumulate the input and store the key in the cache.

As you mentioned, this approach has scalability issues because the cache will grow infinitely. To get around this problem, you can use a cache with expiration and eviction features. The simplest way to go about this would be to explictly set the "expires at" of every key you write. This is supported by Mongo, Memcached, and Redis.

The problem is, even if you set "expires at" on every point, with enough load your cache will still go out of memory. So you need a fallback - something to do when the cache is out of memory. For this you can use a cache with "auto-eviction" functionality which means it has an algorithm to delete things when it has to.

It doesn't look like Mongo supports anything like this (it's a database with cache features rather than a proper cache). Memcache uses an LRU algorithm (see https://github.com/memcached/memcached/wiki/UserInternals#when-are-items-evicted). Redis has multiple algorithms you can pick from (see https://redis.io/topics/lru-cache).

The one other thing I would keep in mind, is that doing this whole process on a distributed or multithreaded application introduces race conditions. Say you have 20 worker machines which for whatever reason all get the same message at almost exactly the same time. Each of them will check the cache for an entry and will find nothing, so none of them are marked as duplicate.

To get around this issue you can use mutexes/semaphores for multiple threads running on the same machine (vertical scaling) or a "distributed lock" if you have multiple machines entirely (horizontal scaling). See https://redis.io/topics/distlock

*edit*

I received a tip that Mongo can do auto-eviction with [Capped Collections](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/capped-collections/). It only supports FIFO eviction (always expires oldest data first) which may work for your needs anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If your JSON message can be applied in any order, then the timestamp approach does not seem to make much sense.  The description of the problem is not very clear about this -- only about the need to make sure that you avoid reprocessing the same message.

I worked on system with a similar constraint and the approach that we took was to focus on the *message* rather than the resource.  The approach was to calculate an MD5 checksum of the message (or at least the critical pieces as it would affect the MyResource instance... including the resource ID).  You'll store the message in a mongoDB doc, perhaps the entire message as one attribute and the MD5 checksum in another.  When the worker receives the message, it calculates the checksum for the message, checks to see if the message has already been received, and only processes the message (store in mongoDB, take action on MyResource instance) if there's not existing doc with that checksum.

One advantage of this approach is that you can "play back" the messages in the future if, for some reason, the 'take action on MyResource' piece falls over.  You might want to timestamp the doc *when you receive it* to guarantee playback order (since production is asynchronous... and you might want to support multiple producers... the receipt time should be king).

Answer (score 0):

let me share another crazy solution. if you can assign unique prime numbers for each Resource messages then you can identify duplicates. in a situation like this, you have to trade off between space and time.

```
messages for MyResource 1 => message 2 | message 3 | message 5 | message 7  
messages for MyResource 2 => message 2 | message 3 | message 5 | message 7
```

after each process, you store multiplication of current message prime number and previous calculation.

```
MyResource 1 | 2  (processed 2 only)  
MyResource 2 | 70 (processed 2*5*7)
```

whenever you got a message, validate whether existing value can divide by message id.

```
70 % 5 == 0 true (already processed)
70 % 3 == 0 false (not processed)
```

in your number two option, you worry about space(MongoDB 15mb limitation, insert/lookup latency), for that, you should consider space-efficient data structures like `bloom filter`. however it's a probabilistic data structure, which means false positive matches are possible, but false negatives are not. [redis has a nice implementation](https://redislabs.com/blog/rebloom-bloom-filter-datatype-redis/) you can try.

```
 127.0.0.1:6379> BF.ADD resource1 msg1
 (integer) 1
 127.0.0.1:6379> BF.EXISTS resource1 msg1
 (integer) 1
 127.0.0.1:6379> BF.EXISTS resource1 msg2
 (integer) 0
```